# Rename file containing substring 'foo' with 'bar'

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, command-line

I want to rename all files which contain the sub-string '`foo`', replacing it with '`bar`' within a given folder.How can I accomplish this?

Update:

```
for i in ./*foo*; do mv "$i" "${i//foo/bar}";done
```

works!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the `rename(1)` that came with `perl` (Debian provides it), you can use:

```
cd /path/to/directory
rename 's/foo/bar/g' *
```

If you have the other `rename(1)` (I've seen it in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and some other distributions, it comes from util-linux), you can try:

```
cd /path/to/directory
rename foo bar *foo*
```

You can check which version of `rename` you have by trying `rename -V`. If it doesn't recognize the flag, it's the perl version. If it prints version information, it's the other version.

Comment: I am trying something like `for i in ./*foo*; do mv "$i" "${i//foo/bar}";done` but not sure if it works

Comment: can u suggest other alternatives without using rename command

Comment: @usercr: The one-liner you provided should work. Try `for f in *foo*; do echo mv "${i}" "${i//foo/bar}"; done` to see what it will do. Remove the `echo` to do it for real.